# Using Typescript generics in a callback invoking a React useState setter

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, typescript-generics, react-typescript

According to Typescript, this code has the following problem: `Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<T>'.ts(2345)`.

A similar version with a type or a type union in place of the generic would work (in fact a union with all the expected types would probably be recommended).

Still, if I wanted to stick with generics how would I modify this code so that it is accepted?

```
import React, { Dispatch, SetStateAction, useState } from 'react';

function useValue<T>(init: T) {
  return useState<T>(init);
}

function SpecialButton<T>({
  value,
  setValue,
}: {
  value: T;
  setValue: Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>;
}) {
  switch (typeof value) {
    case 'number':
      return <button onClick={() => setValue(value + 1)}>Add 1 to {value}</button>;
    default:
      return <div>UNSUPPORTED</div>;
  }
}

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useValue<number>(0);
  return <SpecialButton value={value} setValue={setValue} />;
}
```

(Also, I noticed that in the case of type equal to number value would be cast to `T | number`, but I'm not sure how to take advantage of that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can suggest you the next approach of narrowing types:

```
function useValue<T>(init: T) {
  return useState<T>(init);
}

type Parameters<T> = {
  value: T;
  setValue: Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>;
};

const isNumberParams = (parameters: { value: unknown }): parameters is Parameters<number> =>
  typeof parameters.value === 'number';

const isStringParams = (parameters: { value: unknown }): parameters is Parameters<string> =>
  typeof parameters.value === 'string';

function SpecialButton<T>(params: Parameters<T>) {
  if (isNumberParams(params)) {
    return (
      <button onClick={() => params.setValue(params.value + 1)}>Add 1 to {params.value}</button>
    );
  }
  if (isStringParams(params)) {
    return (
      <button onClick={() => params.setValue(params.value + '1')}>Add 1 to {params.value}</button>
    );
  }
  return <div>UNSUPPORTED</div>;
}

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useValue<number>(0);
  return <SpecialButton value={value} setValue={setValue} />;
}
```

Comment: I had found that narrowing types would be somehow related, but I didn't know how to implement it. The `is` keyword pattern still feels a bit strange, but it seems useful (not entirely sure if I prefer a union over this or not).

Answer (score 0):

I would try declaring a custom type like this:

```
import React, { Dispatch, SetStateAction, useState } from 'react'  

// Declare custom Type:
type StateActionType<T> = SetStateAction<T>
```

Then you use it at you `SpecialButton` declaration:

```
// Use the custom Type:
function SpecialButton<T>({ value, setValue } : {
    value: T,
    setValue: Dispatch<StateActionType<T>>
}) {
```

Comment: To me this still yields `Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'StateActionType<T>'.ts(2345)`